# SyntaxError: invalid property id - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am from an Oracle PLSQL background and I have just started learning MongoDB commands.

```
   >db.Employee.find()
   { "_id" : 10, "EmployeeName" : "Smith" }
   { "_id" : 20, "EmployeeName" : "Nandhi" }
   { "_id" : 30, "EmployeeName" : "Rajan" }
   { "_id" : 50, "EmployeeName" : "Raju" }
```

I need to query the documents like:

```
  WHERE EmployeeName = "Smith" OR (EmployeeName = "Rajan" AND _id = 30);
```

I have written the corresponding code as below:

```
  db.Employee.find({$or:[{"EmployeeName":"Smith",{"EmployeeName":"Rajan","_id":30}}]})
```

**Error Message**

> 2019-03-13T22:48:26.123+0530 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: invalid
>   property id @(shell):1:47

Comment: You are missing to separate the two conditions, each `or` condition should be inside {}.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$or` terms need to be in separate objects:

```
db.Employee.find({$or:[{"EmployeeName":"Smith"}, {"EmployeeName":"Rajan", "_id":30}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Braces are incorrectly enclosed. Use like this

```
  db.Employee.find({$or:[{"EmployeeName":"Smith"},{"EmployeeName":"Rajan","_id":30}]})
```